# Comparing the contents of two csv files, where the relation between the two files is specified in a third file?

Tags: mysql, bash, pandas, csv

I have two files with sales data, and I want to validate whether the sales numbers in the first file are the same as the sales numbers in the second file. But the product ID used in each file are different. I do have a 3rd file with the the correspondence between the old product ID and the new product ID.

Old Sales file

```
Product ID   Store ID  Week ID  Sales 
a               1       201801   5
a               2       201801   4
a               2       201802   3 
b               1       201801   3
b               2       201802   4
b               3       201801   2  
c               2       201802   2
```

New Sales file

```
Product ID   Store ID  Week ID  Sales 
X               1       201801   5
X               2       201801   4
X               2       201802   3 
Y               1       201801   5
Y               2       201802   4
Y               3       201801   2  
Z               2       201802   2
```

And an Old product ID/New Product ID correspondence file:

```
Old Product ID     New Product ID 
      a                   X
      b                   Y
      c                   Z
```

I want to run a script or a command that could verify if the sales are the same for each product/store/week combination in both files. That is: 
If a and X designated the same product, then I want to check if for a given store and a given week the sales will always match in both file. 
Note that not all product present in the old sales file are necessarily present in the new sales file.

The output should look like:

```
Product ID   Store ID   Week ID  Sales Diff
 X               1       201801      0
 X               2       201801      0
 X               2       201802      0 
 Y               1       201801      2
 Y               2       201802      0
 Y               3       201801      0  
 Z               2       201802      0
```

I'm thinking of either pulling all 3 files into a bunch of pandas data frames and then merging and doing the validation using pandas merge and difference utilities, or pulling the files into some redshift tables and using SQL to validate. But both seem like overkill. Is there a simpler way of doing this using command line/bash utilities?

Comment: I don't think that treating relational data tables like relational data is overkill. I'd use SQLite for this, but same idea.

Comment: your `pandas` approach sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: I second Quang, pandas can easily handle this depending on the file size. Although SQL would probably be better with a stored procedure of some sort. How big are your files?

Comment: @QuangHoang about 600M for each sales file. the correspondence file is a bit smaller.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a fan of the "do it in sql" approach, specifically, sqlite:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

oldsales="$1"
newsales="$2"
junction="$3"

# Import into database. Do once and reuse if running repeated reports on the same data
if [ ! -f sales.db ]; then
    sqlite3 -batch sales.db <<EOF
CREATE TABLE old_sales(product_id TEXT, store_id INTEGER, week_id INTEGER, sales INTEGER
                     , PRIMARY KEY(product_id, store_id, week_id)) WITHOUT ROWID;
CREATE TABLE new_sales(product_id TEXT, store_id INTEGER, week_id INTEGER, sales INTEGER
                     , PRIMARY KEY(product_id, store_id, week_id)) WITHOUT ROWID;
CREATE TABLE mapping(old_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, new_id TEXT) WITHOUT ROWID;
.mode csv
.separator \t
.import '|tail -n +2 "$oldsales"' old_sales
.import '|tail -n +2 "$newsales"' new_sales
.import '|tail -n +2 "$junction"' mapping
.quit
EOF
fi

# And query it
sqlite3 -batch sales.db <<EOF
.headers on
.mode list
.separator \t
SELECT n.product_id AS "Product ID", n.store_id AS "Store ID", n.week_id AS "Week ID"
     , n.sales - o.sales AS "Sales Diff"
FROM old_sales AS o
JOIN mapping AS m ON o.product_id = m.old_id
JOIN new_sales AS n ON m.new_id = n.product_id
                   AND o.store_id = n.store_id
                   AND o.week_id = n.week_id
ORDER BY "Product ID", "Store ID", "Week ID";
.quit
EOF
```

This assumes your data files are delimited by tabs, and produces tab deliminated output (Easy to change if desired). It also caches the data in the file `sales.db` and re-uses that if it exists, so you can run the report multiple times on the same data and only populate the database the first time, for efficiencies's sake.

```sh
$ ./report.sh old_sales.tsv new_sales.tsv product_mappings.tsv
Product ID  Store ID    Week ID Sales Diff
X   1   201801  0
X   2   201801  0
X   2   201802  0
Y   1   201801  2
Y   2   201802  0
Y   3   201801  0
Z   2   201802  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a suggestion for your `pandas` approach. I called your old dataframe `old` and your new dataframe `new`:

First we use your third dataframe as a dictionary to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) the old `Product ID's` to the new ones:

```
product_id_dct = dict(zip(df3['Old Product ID'], df3['New Product ID']))
old['Product ID'] = old['Product ID'].map(product_id_dct)

print(old)
  Product ID  Store ID  Week ID  Sales
0          X         1   201801      5
1          X         2   201801      4
2          X         2   201802      3
3          Y         1   201801      3
4          Y         2   201802      4
5          Y         3   201801      2
6          Z         2   201802      2
```

Then we do a [`left merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on the columns which you want to check the changes on. Note a left merge will give us all the matches, and the differences will show in `NaN`. In this case we don't have any:

```
new.merge(old, on=['Product ID', 'Store ID', 'Week ID', 'Sales'], 
          suffixes=['_new', '_old'], 
          how='left')

  Product ID  Store ID  Week ID  Sales
0          X         1   201801      5
1          X         2   201801      4
2          X         2   201802      3
3          Y         1   201801      3
4          Y         2   201802      4
5          Y         3   201801      2
6          Z         2   201802      2
```

If we leave *sales* out as a `key`, we can compare more easily because of the `suffixes` argument:

```
new.merge(old, on=['Product ID', 'Store ID', 'Week ID'], 
          suffixes=['_new', '_old'], 
          how='left')

  Product ID  Store ID  Week ID  Sales_new  Sales_old
0          X         1   201801          5          5
1          X         2   201801          4          4
2          X         2   201802          3          3
3          Y         1   201801          3          3
4          Y         2   201802          4          4
5          Y         3   201801          2          2
6          Z         2   201802          2          2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
ARGIND==1 { map[$2] = $1; next }
ARGIND==2 { old[$1,$2,$3] = $4; next }
FNR==1 { gsub(/  +/,OFS); sub(/ *$/,"_Diff"); print; next }
{ print $1, $2, $3, $4 - old[map[$1],$2,$3] }

$ awk -f tst.awk map old new | column -s$'\t' -t
Product ID  Store ID  Week ID  Sales_Diff
X           1         201801   0
X           2         201801   0
X           2         201802   0
Y           1         201801   2
Y           2         201802   0
Y           3         201801   0
Z           2         201802   0
```

The above uses GNU awk for `ARGIND`. With other awks just add the line `FNR==1 { ARGIND++ }` just after the `BEGIN` line.